# Implementing a jQuery fallback for the details element

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, css

I'm trying to implement a jQuery fallback for the [`details`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-details-element) element. If you've never heard about it, it is basically a [Disclosure widget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disclosure_widget). If the boolean attribute `open` is present, it indicates that both the summary and the additional information is to be shown to the user. If the attribute is absent, only the summary is to be shown. The following HTML and CSS achieve that.

**HTML**

```
<!-- opened -->
<details open>
    <summary>Summary</summary>
    <p>Additional information</p>
</details>

<!-- closed -->
<details>
    <summary>Summary</summary>
    <p>Additional information</p>
</details>
```

**CSS**

```
details summary ~ * {
    display: none;
}

details[open] summary ~ * {
    display: block;
}
```

I then added the following jQuery to add/remove the `open` attribute when the `summary` element is clicked.

**jQuery**

```
$("summary").click(function() {
    if ($(this).parent().attr("open")) {
        $(this).parent().removeAttr("open");
    } else {
        $(this).parent().attr("open", "open");
    }
});
```

It adds and removes the `open` attribute, however the `p` element's visibility remains unaffected in Chrome. What am I doing wrong? Here is a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/GnKCD/1/).

**Updates**

- It works in Firefox 4.
- [manjii](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166538/manji) pointed out that `open` should be changed to `open="open"` or it will not work the first time. [BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) also provided an alternative solution. This is not the main issue though.
- [marcosfromero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/639430/marcosfromero) and [BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) brought up the issue of Chrome's dynamic styles support, which I think could be related.

Comment: The `p`'s visibility does change when you click again, so it's only broken for the first click.

Comment: @BoltClock It changes in Firefox 4, but not in Chrome. I edited the question to point this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be a WebKit bug reported [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=21346).

> **Bug 21346** attribute value selector
>   not being reevaluated upon attribute
>   change

Adding this empty rule will temporarily fix the issue I was having:

```
details[open] {}
```

Contrary to the description in the bug report, it seems to occur when using an attribute selector followed by a descendant combinator.

However, Chrome 12 was released today and it has native support for the `details` and `summary` elements.

Answer (score 1):

It's not working only the first time, because for:

```
<details open>
```

`$(this).parent().attr("open")` is equal to `""` (empty string) = `false` => the attribute is not removed but given the value `"open"` => second time clicked will work.

To fix this, add a value to the attribute:

```
<details open="open">
```

Comment: Alternatively, `if (typeof $(this).parent().attr("open") != "undefined")`

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, but it is not the main issue. @BoltClock I tried that but it didn't really work in FF4 or Chrome.

Comment: I guess you're not using jQuery 1.6 then, maybe.

Comment: @BoltClock I tried it again, you're right. I must have done something wrong the first time.

Answer (score 1):

### Add Mozilla Firefox support

```
<details>
<summary>Summary</summary>
<p id="detail">Additional information</p>
</details>


<script>
var ischrome = false;
if(/chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())){
    ischrome = true;
    }

$detail = $('#detail');
$detail.hide();
if(!ischrome){
    $('summary').prepend('► ');                     
}
$('summary').on('click', function(e){
    if ($detail.is(":visible")){
        $('summary').html('► summary');
        $detail.hide();                                 
    }else{              
        $('summary').html('▼ summary');             
        $detail.show(); 
    }
});                     
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

At least in Chrome, the problem is not with the jQuery code but with Chrome support for your CSS selectors.

If you debug the jQuery code, it works, but CSS is not applied as intended.

Check this fork of your original code with a "debug console":

http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/KQGn8/

Comment: I know that it adds and removes the `open` attribute correctly, but the CSS is _initially_ applied as intended as you can see. The first `details` element is opened, while the second one is closed.

Comment: WebKit seems to have issues with `~` and dynamic styles.

Comment: @BoltClock `~` is not the problem, because if you replace it with `+` it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

In Safari you will need to add evt.preventDefault() to the click handler, otherwise it will also trigger the native behaviour, returning it to the state it was at before the click (this doesn't seem to happen in Chrome, oddly).

```
$("summary").click(function(evt) {
    if ($(this).parent().attr("open")) {
        $(this).parent().removeAttr("open");
    } else {
        $(this).parent().attr("open", "open");
    }
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607333/2397550) to get it to work on all non-supported browsers. It does not require nor use jQuery, but you can enhance it with jQuery if you like (it is just plain JS).

Here is the solution in action:

```css
details summary {display: block;}    
details summary ~ * {
    display: none;
}
details[open] summary ~ * {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary onclick="if(this.parentElement.getAttribute('open')!='open') this.parentElement.setAttribute('open','open'); else this.parentElement.removeAttribute ('open'); return false;">{{ item.title }}</summary>
  {{ item.content }}
</details>
```

Comment: I am pretty sure SO has a policy against duplicate answers. Why would an answer in a very similar tread go offline? I think this policy only applies to (and is designed for) links to a third party, but I may be wrong.

Comment: UPDATE: I have added the solution to the answer.