# Why isn't the summary and detail tag working?

Tags: html

I have tried this code here. `<details>` and `<summary>` tags are not showing in any of browser I try using. Why?

```html
<details>
  <summary>StudentResult</summary>
  <p> The student result are just average...</p>
</details>
```

Comment: @user3809384 What kind of `<!-- -->` comments do you mean? Can you explain your question a little better? Thanks.

Comment: what is not working, where are your html and body start tags

Comment: @user3809384 Looks normal to me http://jsfiddle.net/g2x7W/

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt its there but every time i push it a line it tells me to add more context. This is my full code and i am wondering why the details and summary part where its supposed to have a drop list not working

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt I have tried this code here 
        <html>
        <body>


         <details>
          <summary>StudentResult</summary>
          <p> The student result are just average...</p>
         </details> 

        </body>
        </html>
Summary and detail tags are not showing in any of browser i try using. Why?

Comment: @redditor i want it to have like a dropdown list. Not a dropdown box. Like where you click Summary arrow and the details drops down from the arrow

Comment: Most browsers (or their older versions) don't support this functionality at all, so you will have to write some script to achieve this functionality yourself. Bottom line is... your code is missing the script part.

Comment: I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607333/2397550) to get it to work on IE and Edge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<details>` and `<summary>` tags are not supported in mozila firefox and internet explorer.
Also they are only supported by any version of google chrome heigher than 12.So, it depends on which browser and which version you are using.

follwing links will help:[summary tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_details.asp) , 
[details tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_details.asp)

Comment: @user3809384 Don't blam urself.:D.

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation. I have negative maybe

Comment: It is supported by all browsers, except IE+Edge http://caniuse.com/#search=details

Comment: 4 years later, still no IE or Edge support. Microsoft really dropping the ball.

Comment: 4 years later and somebody ;-) has written a fallback for non-supporting browsers. You can use this now, as long as you implement the fallback provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22644268/details-and-summary-tag-compatibility-issues?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: can StackExchange support these html tags on questions/answers or not?

Answer (score 2):

try it out:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('#showNow').click(function(){
$('details').slideDown();
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id='showNow'>Show</button>
     <details style='display:none;'>
      <summary>StudentResult</summary>
      <p> The student result are just average...</p>
     </details> 

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the content to be visible by default you need to specify the open attribute.

```
<details open="open">
    <summary>StudentResult</summary>
    <p> The student result are just average...</p>
</details>
```

Keep in mind that not all browsers have a native implementation for this, so you might have to enhance it with some javascript if you want it to work the same in all browsers.

Comment: am lookinbg for something like this but its not appearing eventhough i input the exact code

Comment: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/details-summary-demo.gif

Comment: @user3809384: in which browsers are you testing? In Chrome it works exactly as shown in that GIF.

Comment: @user3809384: yeah like I said, most browsers don't support this functionality. Try the code in nsthethunderbolt answer. It should give you a good starting point.