# How To Add CSS3 Transition With HTML5 details/summary tag reveal?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Using just CSS3, is there a way to add a nice fade-in and slide-from-left transition effect on a `DETAILS`/`SUMMARY` reveal?

For a demo of this new tag, see this demo:

```css
details {
  transition:height 3s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Copyright 1999-2014.</summary>
  <section>
    <p> - by Refsnes Data. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    <p>All content and graphics on this web site are the property of the company Refsnes Data.</p>
  </section>
</details>
```

In my case, after the `summary` tag, I put all other content in its own `section` tag so that I could style it because `summary:after` selector didn't seem to work. I tried using CSS3 transitions on height for the `section` and `details` tag, but it didn't help.

Comment: Please include all of the HTML & CSS in the question itself, in a [mcve]. You may also want to consider using a different reference than w3schools, like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/summary) or even [the standard itself](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-summary-element). Also, HTML elements do not need to be in all uppercase, and  referring to them in that manner makes the question hard to read.

Comment: Note that Edge support is still lacking. I have proposed a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607333/2397550).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In addition to [Volomike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38215801/7724384), it would be possible to change `margin-left` to `transform: translateX()` for performance reasons.

```css
details[open] summary ~ * {
  animation: sweep .5s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes sweep {
  0%    {opacity: 0; transform: translateX(-10px)}
  100%  {opacity: 1; transform: translateX(0)}
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Copyright 1999-2014.</summary>
  <p> - by Refsnes Data. All Rights Reserved.</p>
  <p>All content and graphics on this web site are the property of the company Refsnes Data.</p>
</details>
```

Comment: How do I revert this animation upon closing? Simply adding a `details[close] summary ~ *` property with the same animation but with the property `animation-direction: reverse` did not work.

Comment: @Rich_Rich it's not possible. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details): "Unfortunately, at this time there's no built-in way to animate the transition between open and closed."

Comment: there goes my CSS only dream. Also good to note: On Firefox iOS (and thus presumably on all iOS browsers), closing and re-opening does not replay the animation.

Answer (score 95):

This should fix it.

```css
details[open] summary ~ * {
  animation: sweep .5s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes sweep {
  0%    {opacity: 0; margin-left: -10px}
  100%  {opacity: 1; margin-left: 0px}
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Copyright 1999-2014.</summary>
  <p> - by Refsnes Data. All Rights Reserved.</p>
  <p>All content and graphics on this web site are the property of the company Refsnes Data.</p>
</details>
```

Some credit goes to [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5402397/andrew) for pointing this out. I adapted his answer. Here's how this works. By adding the `[open]` attribute on the `DETAILS` tag, it only fires the animation keyframe when clicked. Then, by adding `SUMMARY ~ *` it means "all elements after the `SUMMARY` tag" so that the animation applies to those, and not the `SUMMARY` element as well.

Comment: this works well only if you have nothing after the <details>.

Comment: @fcalderan not so -- I've implemented it on FAQs with multiples of these.

Comment: @Felipe & Volomike, if you want to add a new method, that's one thing, but completely changing to a different method is more or less against Stack Overflow policy.

Comment: Consider [Felipe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67814400/105539) due to performance reasons. He's made a small improvement.

Comment: It's a good solution ! But the animation is only triggered the first time on Chrome (looks ok on Firefox)

Comment: @KCarnaille did you figure out a solution for Chrome? I want to restart the animation on Chrome.

Answer (score 47):

For those looking for an open/close transition, it's possible to fake it by `margin-bottom` property.

```css
details {
  background: gainsboro;
  padding: 10px;
}

details summary {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: margin 150ms ease-out;
}

details[open] summary {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary><code>&lt;details&gt;</code> pseudo content transition</summary>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia amet magnam fugit nihil delectus, id ratione deleniti minima, ipsum accusantium exercitationem est ipsa, possimus harum distinctio consequatur qui recusandae et. Alias quas temporibus aliquam modi nulla omnis unde atque magni tempora, corporis ducimus voluptas, recusandae, repellendus officiis molestias cumque quam.
</details>
```

Comment: This is the only answer where animation works on opening & closing the Details tags again. All other answers works only on first open of details tag.

Comment: For some reason I don't understand, when the contents of the `<details>` are wrapped in certain tags, like `<h1>` or `<p>`, then the animation only plays on closing and not opening.

Comment: Genius approach: since only the visible (summary) element's css is changed, it works every time.

Answer (score 13):

```css
details
{
    transition: height 1s ease;
    overflow: hidden;
}

details:not([open])
{
    height: 1.25em;
}

details[open]
{
    height: 2.50em;
}
```

```html
<details>
    <summary>Example</summary>
    Height needs to be set for this to work. Works on Chrome, haven't tested further.
</details>
```

I recommend you also check out Animate.css here: http://daneden.me/animate. If

Comment: Unfortunately, my height needs to be auto because it's unpredictable.

Answer (score 8):

I think a true CSS3 details summary reveal should be done like this (no fixed height and no javascript):

```css
@keyframes animate {
  from {grid-template-rows: 0fr;}
  to {grid-template-rows: 1fr;}
}
details > div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 0fr;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
details > div > div {
  overflow: hidden;
}
details[open] > div {
  animation: animate 0.15s 0s 1 normal forwards;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Lorem ipsum</summary>
  <div>
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus suscipit neque vestibulum elit vehicula luctus. Aenean eget rutrum felis. Ut blandit, massa vitae pulvinar suscipit, nunc lorem pulvinar metus, sed elementum lectus erat euismod eros. Aliquam ac metus id tortor maximus mollis. Sed semper pulvinar risus. Mauris orci mauris, blandit tempus dolor sed, tincidunt pharetra nisi. Cras pulvinar ligula eu sapien cursus, in malesuada diam volutpat. Ut eleifend risus vitae eros pretium rhoncus. Nunc diam nibh, pharetra et orci eu, rutrum congue augue. Etiam quis tempor tortor. Pellentesque nec faucibus mi. Curabitur vitae tempus lorem.
    </div>
  </div>
</details>
<details>
  <summary>Lorem ipsum</summary>
  <div>
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus suscipit neque vestibulum elit vehicula luctus. Aenean eget rutrum felis. Ut blandit, massa vitae pulvinar suscipit, nunc lorem pulvinar metus, sed elementum lectus erat euismod eros. Aliquam ac metus id tortor maximus mollis. Sed semper pulvinar risus. Mauris orci mauris, blandit tempus dolor sed, tincidunt pharetra nisi. Cras pulvinar ligula eu sapien cursus, in malesuada diam volutpat. Ut eleifend risus vitae eros pretium rhoncus. Nunc diam nibh, pharetra et orci eu, rutrum congue augue. Etiam quis tempor tortor. Pellentesque nec faucibus mi. Curabitur vitae tempus lorem.
    </div>
  </div>
</details>

<br>
<br>

Inspired by <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B_n4YONte5A">Kevin Powell</a>
```

Comment: This only works for the first couple of clicks. If I click over and over again the details eventually stop sliding and abruptly open

Comment: fwiw... you can combine your solution with this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69958043/animate-a-details-tag-when-closing). It takes minimal javascript to listen to animation end and click events

Answer (score 4):

My styling…

Using `max-height` for transition instead of `height` you can have unknown height (smaller than `99rem`) of content in opened details.

```css
details {
  margin: 1.3rem 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 1.5rem; /* set to line height */
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
}

details[open] {
  max-height: 99rem;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

details summary {
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: -0.5em -0.5em 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

details[open] summary {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin-bottom: 0.8em;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Something like… question?</summary>
  And some very, very long explanation of summarised text. And some very, very long explanation of summarised text. And some very, very long explanation of summarised text
</details>
```

Comment: The text just appears, it doesn't have a transition or animation at all. You can see this by increasing the transition duration.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to simply avoid `<details>` altogether and instead rely on some checkbox trickery:

```css
.toggle {
  appearance: none;
  display: none;
}

.toggle+label:before {
  content: "⯈";
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0;
  transition: transform .5s;
}

.toggle:checked+label:before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.toggle~.details {
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .5s, opacity .5s;
}

.toggle:checked~.details {
  max-height: 100vh;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="toggle0" class="toggle" type="checkbox">
  <label for="toggle0">
    This is the summary
  </label>
  <div class="details">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus felis eget ligula pretium, a feugiat turpis commodo. Quisque nunc ligula, posuere eget lacus vel, condimentum convallis nulla. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
    et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam consectetur lobortis libero, at pulvinar turpis. Sed semper leo id quam vestibulum, id bibendum dolor molestie. Nam eu porttitor est, et facilisis neque. Nullam id ultrices nibh, vel lacinia velit. Pellentesque
    habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Integer egestas ut nibh eget maximus. Etiam quis odio dignissim, facilisis orci vitae, fermentum eros. Proin luctus felis et nunc ultrices, sed rhoncus est finibus.
  </div>
</div>
Some text below.
```

**Caveat:** since we transition `max-height` between 0 and 100vh, this won't work if the height of the content is larger than the height of the window. In that case, you can either use a larger number or add `overflow: auto` to `.toggle:checked~.details` (so that you get a scrollbar).

---

**EDIT:** Alternatively, we could achieve something similar using some Javascript as well:

```js
function onClick(event) {
  let details = event.target.parentElement;
  
  details.style['overflow'] = 'hidden';
  
  if (details.open) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function () {
      details.open = false;
      details.style['overflow'] = 'visible';
    }, 500);
    details.style['max-height'] = '1em';
  } else {
    details.style['max-height'] = '100vh';
  }
}

window.onload = function () {
  for (summary of document.getElementsByTagName('summary')) {
    summary.addEventListener('click', onClick);
  }
}
```

```css
details {
  transition: max-height .5s;
  max-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>
    This is the summary
  </summary>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus felis eget ligula pretium, a feugiat turpis commodo. Quisque nunc ligula, posuere eget lacus vel, condimentum convallis nulla. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
  et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam consectetur lobortis libero, at pulvinar turpis. Sed semper leo id quam vestibulum, id bibendum dolor molestie. Nam eu porttitor est, et facilisis neque. Nullam id ultrices nibh, vel lacinia velit. Pellentesque
  habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Integer egestas ut nibh eget maximus. Etiam quis odio dignissim, facilisis orci vitae, fermentum eros. Proin luctus felis et nunc ultrices, sed rhoncus est finibus.
</details>
Some text below.
```

Note that this has the same problem as before, but additionally won't work if the summary takes up more than one line. Also, glyphs containing descenders (g, j, p, q, y, ç, ŋ, µ, ...) flicker slightly when closing.

Answer (score 0):

You probably would want to use a CSS animation using the `keyframes` if you don't plan on having it appear when you hover over it. If you only want the animation to appear, say, when you see details/summary description on the page, you could use some jQuery so that the browser adds the class of the animation when scrolling.

https://jsfiddle.net/22e95bxt/

Is this what you're looking for?

**Edit: Whoops. This is NOT what you're asking for. My bad!**

Comment: It's close. Looks like you need to use the [open] and :not([open]) selectors to improve it, which is what I'm working on.

Comment: Your answer looks to be the best if you could remove the bold edit and then switch your selector to like `DETAILS[open] SECTION` that fires the animation. That way, it only happens on the click.