# State Variables in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm playing around with some Expand Boxes.

I'm trying to create an HTML + CSS Expand Box without using JavaScript.

For now my code looks something like this:

```js
/* no js */
```

```css
.expand_box{}
.expand_box > .expand_box_checkbox{
  display: none;
}
.expand_box > .expand_box_headline{}
.expand_box > .expand_box_content{
  display: none;
}
.expand_box > .expand_box_checkbox:checked + .expand_box_headline + .expand_box_content{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="expand_box">
  <input  id="eb1" class="expand_box_checkbox" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="eb1" class="expand_box_headline">click me</label>
  <div class="expand_box_content">
    Content to see after clicking on "click me"
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, this is actually a nice solution, as it doesn't depend on JS and runs on practically every device.

---

What I am wondering about:

I am using the checkbox as a storage for state-information.
But this piece of information technically doesn't belong into the HTML, as I only use it for styling.

Is there any way to keep track of the state "user activated the 'click me' button", using pure CSS?

I know of the existence of CSS-variables. Maybe I can use them in some way?

Comment: [CSS Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) are used for data that will be reused throughout a stylesheet. They're actually a bit misnamed since they're more like "CSS Constants".

Comment: Jeah, thats what it looks like to me too. :/

Comment: So you basically want to have an "click me" that when clicked twice doesn't hide the text?

Comment: It should work like that snippet:
start: hide content
1. click: show content
2. click: hide content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 has a native control for expand box. It's `details`/`summary` elements. In [supporting browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=details) it doesn't need  JS and needs CSS only for custom styling. It may need a bit of JS only to work in non-supporting browsers (as a polyfill).

Besides hidden checkbox hack, CSS itself has another possibility to "emulate" states with the very long transition delay (like described [here](http://joelb.me/blog/2012/maintaining-css-style-states-using-infinite-transition-delays/), warning: the example uses unitless `0` value of `transition-duration` which seems not working anymore, but it works with `0s` instead). But these solutions are also too hacky. CSS was never supposed to *maintain* states, but it's excellent in *presenting* them.

Comment: This is awesome. ty so much.
I didn't know about <details>.

Comment: Is it possible to css-select the <details>-box with a pseudo-selector to determine if it is opened or closed?
I'd like to animate the content with a scrolldown-effect.

Comment: Yes, `<details>` has the `open` attribute that reflects the open state, so you can target it from CSS. Here is another anwser with the example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38215801/2533215

Comment: As "[]" is an attribute-selector, I thought, it wouldn't work, when the box is initially closed. It looks like it does though, which is awesome.  Lots of thanks again!