# What is the browser support for element.removeAttribute?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

The summary/details HTML5 element has terrible browser support. Therefore I built [a non-jQuery fallback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607333/2397550) to make it work in non-supported browsers (IE and Edge). This fallback uses element.removeAttribute, but I am in doubt about the browser support of this command. I cannot find a definitive answer online. I have tried [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=removeAttribute) and [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute), but they have no clear answers.

I know it works in my (updated) version of Firefox. Anyone has more info?

Comment: That is the EXACT link I submitted in my question. It contains mostly questionmarks.

Comment: Meaning that the support is unknown or not stable. W3Schools conflicts and says all modern broswers support it. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeattribute.asp

Comment: @daddygames — "We don't know" is not in conflict with "Someone else says they know"

Comment: @Quentin I'm simply supporting the OP by confirming that different sources have different information on the topic. However, I would lean towards the MDN being more accurate, which is to say that support is not guaranteed and you should test specific browsers/versions if you can.

Comment: I think it is just such as old part of the spec that support is as good as universal and nobody has bothered to test it and update MDN's wiki.

Comment: I don't get it... why is this question so bad? I would really like to know the browser support. I can fire up all my VM's to find this out, but I would rather find this on SO or another trustworthy website.

Comment: @JoostS I removed my down vote on the question. However, I don't believe you're going to get any better answer than the docs referenced. MDN is usually the most up-to-date online document publicly available.

Comment: Can you add that as an answer? It is somewhat unsatisfying, but I am willing to accept that, as I am simply asking for 'more info'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method does not work consistently across browsers. It is [BROKEN on MS Edge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/12087679/) at least, and its brokenness is not mentioned by MDN, W3schools or caniuse at time of writing.

Basically, the method will fail when removing [boolean attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139786/what-does-it-mean-in-html-5-when-an-attribute-is-a-boolean-attribute) such as `selected` or `hidden`. The following will fail on Edge:

```
someDiv.removeAttribute("hidden");
```

Workaround is to set the attribute to "false" immediately before removing it.

```
someDiv.setAttribute("hidden", "false"); // "thanks" for the nonsense, MS
someDiv.removeAttribute("hidden");
```

This is not how boolean attributes are supposed to work, but that's how Edge requires it. Given that Edge is about to be dropped by Microsoft in favour of a Chromium-based alternative, we can expect this bug to remain unfixed, and the workaround to clutter our code for years.

Comment: Thanks JoostS! I've since raised a flag about this issue at both caniuse and MDN